# Output variable in unix with new lines as \n

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, unix

I need to output a variable value to a file in a unix script. My problem it that the variable contains multiple lines. I need those to be output as '\n' literals in the file (a java options file), but I'm using echo and they always get processed into real new lines.

```
echo "-dmyproperty=$MULTILINE_VAR" >> jvm.options
```

I've tried echo options like -e o -E but they don't seem to do anything. Can anyone help?

Comment: The `-e/-E` options would be used to go from `\n` to a real newline; going the other direction is tricker.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use bash [parameter substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) with an [ANSI-C quoted newline](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting)

```
$ var="line1
line2
line3"
$ echo "${var//$'\n'/\\n}"
line1\nline2\nline3
```

Comment: If you introduce a new backquote, you have to quote all already existing backquotes in your input data. Otherwise you are not able to get back your original value.

Comment: Sorry, what? Can you give an example?

Comment: Not in a comment.

Comment: that's not a problem, the contents of the variable are a private ssh key, so it will be mainly Base64... thanks!!!

Comment: btw, incidentally, in the meantime I came across using something very simmilar as a solution: echo "${var//$'\n'/'\n'}" but really I didn't understand why it worked, as the string to substitute and the substitution were the same :-m

Comment: not the same: `$'\n'` with the ANSI-C quoting is a one-character string: a newline -- `'\n'` in single quotes is a two-character string: a backslash and "n"